# Access actions in embed FXML

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml

Structure of my application is approximately like this MainApplication->SuperFXMLController->ChildFXMLController. Every ChildFXML has a button to add one more child element to the GridPane in SuperFXML I have defined buttonHandler method in ChildFXMLController but the action itself should be happening in SuperFXMLController (add new row in grid). The question is how to handle the action from SuperFXMLController?

Here some code details:
AddLogRecordController.java (so called "SuperFXMLController"):

```
@FXML
private void initialize() throws IOException {
rowIndex = 0;

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("RecordGrid.fxml"));

    mainGrid.add(loader.load(), 0, rowIndex++);
    RecordGridController controller = (RecordGridController) loader.getController();
    controller.setSuperController(this);
}
...
public void addRowHandle() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("RecordGrid.fxml"));

        mainGrid.getChildren().add(loader.load());
        RecordGridController controller = loader.getController();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

"RecordGridController" referred as "ChildFXMLController":

```
private AddLogRecordController superController;
...
public void setSuperController(AddLogRecordController addLogRecordControllerClass) {
    this.superController = addLogRecordControllerClass;
}
...
@FXML
private void addRowHandler() {
    superController.addRowHandle();
}
```

And this is result window where the section surrounded by red is a child fxml that should be duplicated as many times as button Add to QSO pressed:
[image: And this is result window where the section surrounded by red is a child fxml that should be duplicated as many times as button Add to QSO pressed]

Comment: Use a MVC approach: share the data model with the child controller, and observe the data model in the parent controller. Then just add data to the model in the button handler in the child controller.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it? I'm newbuy

Comment: The details of the implementation will depend quite considerably on the relationship between your different FXML files and controllers. If you want a more specific answer, you need to be a lot more specific in the question. Create an example application - a [MCVE] - that demonstrates what you are trying to do, and include it in your question.

Comment: I have add some code and screenshot, hope that will help. As you see I will have to work a lot with the fields from embedded fxml, and this fxml will be embedded several times. I have this done in PHP and actively using it, so, can tell that "red" block repeated up to 20 times in average before actually Submit button pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I made it to do what it should by plan. I have add following method in SuperController:

```
private void loadRecordGrid(int rowIndex) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("RecordGrid.fxml"));

        mainGrid.add(loader.load(), 0, rowIndex);
        RecordGridController controller = (RecordGridController) loader.getController();
        controller.initialize(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then method initialize like this:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    rowIndex = 0;
    loadRecordGrid(rowIndex++);
}
```

And method addRowHandler like this:

```
public void addRowHandle() {
    loadRecordGrid(rowIndex++);
}
```

in ChildController:

```
private AddLogRecordController superController;

@FXML
public void initialize(AddLogRecordController superController) {
    this.superController = superController;
}


@FXML
private void addRowHandler() {
    superController.addRowHandle();
}
```

Do not know, maybe it can be done more efficient way, but this works for now. 
Now I will need to figure how to pass values of the textfields from child to parent and back